Supervised vs unsupervised learning - is not all data labelled?
I have never really had a clear understanding of the difference betweeen supervised and unsupervised learning.
If you ask a search engine what the difference between the two categories is, you will get an answer along the lines of the following:

supervised learning requires labelled data whereas unsupervised learning does not

This still isn't clear to me.
Is it not the case that all data is labelled? If you have data, then that data must have some numerical or categorical value. Therefore it is labelled, with a value.
This may seem pedantic, and perhaps the answer seems obvious. My guess would be that the expression labelled here means with some auxillary categorical label.
Can anyone comment on this or clarify further?
